# How do I make 1 for-loop for multiple integers?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, int

Is there a way to only use one for loop with multiple integers? Currently I have only written the code for int num0. But is there a way to have the rest of num1,num2,num3 in the same code? Reason why I ask for this here is because I am not that experienced as a programmer and I wonder if you guys know if there is a solution. (Pardon my bad grammar)

```
    public void exercise1c() {
      int num0, num1, num2, num3;

      num0 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
      num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
      num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
      num3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));

      for (int i = 0; i <= num0; i++) {
        if (num0 <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Number "+ num0 + " is negative.");
            break;
        }
      }
      if (num0 >= 0) {
        System.out.println(num0 + " is a integer.");
      }
      if (num0 == 0){
        System.out.println(num0 + " is zero.");
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this loop? This current loop does nothing. Is there omitted code?

Comment: what do you mean with one loop with multiple integers?  Some aclaration could be nice... Do you mean getting something like:

1 1 1 1,
1 1 1 2,
...
1 1 2 1,
...
n n n n???

Comment: I think you need to put `if (num0 >= 0)` and `if (num0 == 0)` blocks inside `for` loop too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `num0, num1, num2, num3` in to a `List` or an `array`, Then you can use single `for` loop

Eg: with `int[]`

```
int[] num = new int[4];
num[0] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
num[1] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
num[2] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
num[3] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
   if (num[i] < 0) {
      System.out.println("Number " + num[i] + " is negative.");
      break;
   }
   if (num[i] > 0) {
      System.out.println(num[i] + " is a integer.");
   }
   if (num[i] == 0) {
      System.out.println(num[i] + " is zero.");
   }
}
```

How to do this with `List`

Eg:

```
  List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();
  numList.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number.")));
  numList.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number.")));
  numList.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number.")));
  numList.add(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number.")));

    for (Integer i :numList) {
        if (i < 0) {
            System.out.println("Number " + i + " is negative.");
            break;
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.println(i + " is a integer.");
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println(i + " is zero.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: an `Array` is not the same as an array (nor a `List`).  an array is not an `Object` in java.  You mean `Array` class, but then you write the code using arrays of int, you are going to make him do more mistakes than he has now.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
int[] num = new int[4];

num[0] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
num[1] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
num[2] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
num[3] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));

for(int i = 0; i<num.length; i++) {
    int currentInteger = num[i];

    //other code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, those objects num# aren't arrays but primitives, if they were integers.
If the three Arrays are of the same length the answer is yes!

```
for (int i =0; i < numArray.length; i++)
```

But if you are looking for a quick way of iterating in an array

```
for (int i : numArray)
     System.out.println("The number is: " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do like this:**

```
int num[]=new int[4];

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       num[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
    }

   // Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
static final int N = 4; // <-- the number of integers you have.
public void exercise1c() {
    int num[] = new int [4];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       num[i] = Integer.ParseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number."));
       // you need here some means to get the number into num[i].
    } /* for */
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (num[i] < 0) { // < 0 for negative number.  0 is not negative.
            System.out.println("Number " + num[i] + " is negative.");
            // break; // don't know what you pretend here.
        } else if (num[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println("Number " + num[i] + " is positive.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number " + num[i] + " is zero.");
        } /* if */
    } /* for */
} /* exercise1c() */
```

Comment: What should happen in your first loop? You're not storing the entered number to any variable.

Comment: I know... see the comments.  With the level of java he seems to have, better to do console input before trying to do it with dialog classes.

Comment: He already used the dialog correctly, but wrote the user input in a `int` variable instead of an array. And can you tell me what `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a number.").getText()` is supposed to do? There is no `getText()` method in `String`.

Comment: Ok, in that case the commented line would be ok, or without calling the getText() method, but that was not the thing he was asking. I'll correct that, but it's not well explained what this fellow wants to do either.